# git-http-backend blocking with fastcgi on nginx

Tags: nginx, web-server, git, fastcgi, socket

I have `git-http-backend` serving git repos through an nginx fastcgi proxy. The nginx config looks like:

```
server {
    listen               443 ssl;
    server_name          git.example.com;

    auth_basic           "Git Access";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd_git;
    error_log            /var/log/nginx-git-error.log;
    access_log           /var/log/nginx-git-access.log;
    client_max_body_size 0;

    root /var/git/;

    location ~ /git(/.*) {

        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        include       fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME     /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
        fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT    /var/git;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER         $remote_user;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO           $1;
        fastcgi_read_timeout              600;
    }
}
```

From testing, it seems like if there is more than one request at a time, the proxy will fail (with code 504), and some googling seems to confirm my suspicion that `git-http-backend` cannot support multiple requests.

How do I set this up so that multiple requests to the git repo can be made at once?